# JS create array by comparing 2 dictionaries

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, iteration

I have 2 dictionaries that I have to compare, if an element of one dictionary exists in the other dictionary, then add the element to an array but only one time...

here the working code

```
const getFavouriteShows = (graphql, favouriteShows) => {
    const arraya = [];

    //iterate trough favouriteShows
    for (let item in favouriteShows) {
      //iterate trough graphql
      for (let itemGQL in graphql) {
        //if same slug, add the item to new array JUST ONE TIME
          if(favouriteShows[item].slug === graphql[itemGQL].show?.slug){
            arraya.push(graphql[itemGQL])
            break
          }
      }
    }
       return Object.assign(arraya)
  }
```

So, how to express this in a more inline functional way? using map, filter.

Thanks!

Edit, examples for the data coming in and out https://gist.github.com/mako34/44301d3c96249de9a07aa2550ca1172a

Comment: Can you provide some example inputs and outputs?

Comment: thanks @TedBrownlow link with sample data added

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

### Review

- Use semicolons. Why? If you don't know why you should use them, then you should use them. Not using them can result in very hard to track down bugs that will waste hours of your valuable time.
- Use `const` wherever and whenever possible.
- The return expression `Object.assign(arraya)` does nothing and is not required ( [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) returns the first argument unchanged if there is only one argument). `return arraya;` will do the same.
- Use [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) rather than [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). When you use `for in` you need to ensure that the key belongs to the object which just makes the code more complex. If you dont check for own property [Object.hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) then you risk the code not working for reasons unrelated to your code.

  To get the keys of an object use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) eg you can then replace the for in with `for (let item of Object.keys(favouriteShows)) {`

  As it is only the value `slug` you want from each item in the object `favouriteShows` you can further refine the for of loop to get that value for you. Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) which will get the value you find with `favouriteShows[item]` and use destructure assignment to pull out `slug` thus (Note the `const`) you have `for (const {slug} of Object.values(favouriteShows)) {`
- Avoid naming variables after what they are, rather name them for what they represent (Unless they represent unknowns). Eg `arraya` would be better as `results`
- Don't use complicated or long names when there is no need. The arguments `(graphql, favouriteShows)` can be simplified to `(graph, shows)` without losing any meaning.

### Problems

There are a number of problems with this code.

1. The statement that matches shows by slug  `if(favouriteShows[item].slug === graphql[itemGQL].show?.slug){` will match any two shows that do not have `slug` defined IE `slug === undefined`

   This is not a problem if all objects always have `slug` defined. However the use of `show?.` makes it clear that this is at least not true in part.

   You can check if slug is defined in the outer loop so you don't waste time searching for undefined in the inner loop.
2. In your question you state  *"...then add the element to an array but only one time."* However if `favouriteShows` contains items that have the same value for `slug` and there is a match for that value in `graphql` your function will add the same entry for every occurrence in `favouriteShows`

   To prevent this problem you can use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to hold the result rather than an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), It will ensure only one copy of each item is added.

### Improvement

The inner loop repeats, stepping over the same items for every item in `favouriteShows`. You can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that indexes items via a generated hash value. This reduces the complexity of your inner loop from \$O(n)\$ to \$O(1)\$.

Thus your code ends up as with added comments

```
// Keep the argument names simple
const favouriteShows = (graph, shows) => {

    // Use set to ensure only a single instance of each item will be in the result
    const result = new Set();  

    // Create a map of graph indexed by slug so the inner loop is not needed.
    const bySlug = new Map(Object.values(graph).map(val => [val.show?.slug, val]));

    // Extract value of slug from the item values in shows
    for (const {slug} of Object.values(shows)) {
        
        // Make sure slug is defined.
        // It is unclear if this value may be falsey so test against undefined
        if (slug !== undefined) {

            // Does the map bySlug have an entry that matches slug?
            if (bySlug.has(slug)) {

                // Yes then get that entry and add it to the result.
                result.add(bySlug.get(slug));
            }
        }
    }

    // To return an array convert the set to an array.
    return [...result.values()];
}
```

It can also be compacted a little, and making an assumption that slug will be either undefined or some truthy string we get

```
const favouriteShows = (graph, shows) => {
    const result = new Set();  
    const bySlug = new Map(Object.values(graph).map(val => [val.show?.slug, val]));
    for (const {slug} of Object.values(shows)) {
        const show = bySlug.get(slug);             
        slug && show && result.add(show);
    }
    return [...result.values()];
}
```

**Note** that `bySlug.get` will find the last entry in the object `graph` if `graph` contained duplicates (`slug` has the same value more than once). As your code uses the first instance you may want to change the second line in the function so that it reverses (via [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)) the order that the map is created. If there are no duplicates then it does not matter.

```
const favouriteShows = (graph, shows) => {
    const result = new Set();  
    const bySlug = new Map(Object.values(graph)
       .map(val => [val.show?.slug, val])
       .reverse()
    );
    for (const {slug} of Object.values(shows)) {
        const show = bySlug.get(slug);             
        slug && show && result.add(show);
    }
    return [...result.values()];
}
```